# Asp.NET MVC 5 IdentityServer4 External Provider

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, identityserver4

With IdentityServer3 one approach to configure external authentication provider was add to the Startup method of the application

```
    internal class Startup
    {
        public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
        {
            var microsoft = new MicrosoftAccountAuthenticationOptions()
            {
                AuthenticationType = "Microsoft",
                ClientId = "********",
                ClientSecret = "********"
            };
            app.UseMicrosoftAccountAuthentication(microsoft);
            ....
        }
    }
```

In IdentityServer4 everything is designed around IApplicationBuilder interface, which doesn't have the methods above.

```
    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
    {
       ....
    }
```

Does this means that in V4 external providers authentication is not supported yet?

I tried unsuccessfully to inject the IAppBuilder in the Configure method, but it would be a pretty messy solution...

Any thoughts? Thank you

Comment: Take a look here, someone is talking about a similar question: https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer3/issues/34

Answer (score 3):

Thanks everyone,

I think I made some significant progresses. The problem was that I was trying to add the old OWIN references to my solution instead of adopting the new AspNet Authentication.

"Microsoft.AspNet.Authentication.MicrosoftAccount": "1.0.0-rc1-final"

I found a solution [here](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=532715).

Event with IApplicationBuilder it is possible to register external providers as detailed below

```
        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
    {
        ...
        app.UseMicrosoftAccountAuthentication(options =>
        {
            options.ClientId = Configuration["AppSettings:AzureClientId"];
            options.ClientSecret = Configuration["AppSettings:AzureClientSecret"];
            options.AuthenticationScheme = "Microsoft";
            options.SignInScheme = "Cookies";
            options.CallbackPath = new PathString("/signin-microsoft");
            options.AuthorizationEndpoint = MicrosoftAccountDefaults.AuthorizationEndpoint;
            options.TokenEndpoint = MicrosoftAccountDefaults.TokenEndpoint;
        });
    }
```

Comment: @federico how do you then get the list of external providers from the login page? In the MVC6 template it uses SignInManager.GetExternalAuthenticationSchemes(), but for IdentityServer4 I don't see how to get that same list... :(

Comment: Context.Authentication.GetAuthenticationSchemes() seems to get the list, but I'm not fully there yet... :( Is there a complete guide somewhere to implement social logins with IdentityServer4?

Comment: Seb, after a long fight with OpenIdConnect I ended up creating my custom jwt based identity server :-)